# Braintree Integration using my custom UI (Without Paypal Option)

Tags: android, braintree

Without Using Braintree Drop-In UI, I want use my custom UI to accept user's credit card details and validate user payments in android.
Please Suggest me any tutorial or example which help me to create my custom UI.

Comment: Have you seen this [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/android/v2#custom-integration)

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

A number of resources exist for implementing a custom UI for Android. The main difference between them is that you must tokenize payment methods manually. Use the CardBuilder class to tokenize your own payment methods.

```
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder()
    .cardNumber("4111111111111111")
    .expirationDate("09/2018");

Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);
```

Visit our [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/client-side/android/v2) to learn more about tokenizing credit cards and other payment methods using our Android SDK.

Additionally visit our [Android SDK reference](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.braintreepayments.api/braintree/2.2.1) and our [Braintree Android Demo](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/tree/master/Demo) for further examples on how to integrate our Android SDK.

Comment: @Pbelsi can I use this if my company's PCI Compliance level is SAQ A? I have posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760552/braintree-android-use-cardbuilder-to-add-credit-card-at-saq-a-pci-compliance-l

Comment: For mobile clients there is [no heightened PCI requirement](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/android/v2#custom-integration) when integrating using our custom integration versus Drop-in

Comment: Any reason why the 4111111111111111 test credit card for sandbox environment continues to come back as invalid?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder 4111111111111111 should be a valid credit card number in sandbox. Validation errors in sandbox can also be triggered by [amounts](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/dotnet#test-amounts). If this does not resolve your issue, reach out to Braintree support (support@braintreepayments.com) for more help.

Comment: @pblesi I actually figured this out, it was because CVV also needed to be included. That info is not offered by the documents or reflected in your answer. But hopefully now others, like myself, won't have the same confusion. Thank you