# Braintree Android - Use Cardbuilder to add credit card at SAQ A PCI Compliance Level

Tags: android, braintree, pci-compliance, pci-dss

I am new to Braintree and I want to have my own custom UI to store Credit card. I am using the following code to tokenize the credit card.

```
CardBuilder cardBuilder = new CardBuilder()
            .cardNumber(mCardForm.getCardNumber())
            .expirationMonth(mCardForm.getExpirationMonth())
            .expirationYear(mCardForm.getExpirationYear());

    Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);
```

I already have PCI SAQ A Compliance level. My question will it be safe carry out this operation considering my PCI level?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

For our mobile clients there is [no heightened PCI requirement](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/android/v2#custom-integration) when integrating using our custom integration versus Drop-in.